Next.js app works locally but shows default page on GitHub Pages after deployment
I'm facing an issue where my Next.js app works perfectly fine locally, but after deploying it to GitHub Pages, it only shows the default Next.js landing page.
Here’s the scenario:

The app runs locally on localhost:3000 without any problems.

I am deploying it to GitHub Pages using GitHub Actions.

The repository https://github.com/mateuszkozlowski/krakow-airport is hosted at https://mateuszkozlowski.github.io/krakow-airport/.


My setup:

Next.js version: 15.0.4

Deployment method: Using GitHub Actions and the gh-pages-deploy-action


The issue:
When I deploy the app to GitHub Pages, it shows the default Next.js welcome page (This is a Next.js project bootstrapped with create-next-app), rather than the expected app content. Locally, the app runs as expected.
What I’ve tried:

I ensured the basePath and assetPrefix are correctly set in next.config.js.

I’ve verified that the out folder contains the exported static files.

I’ve confirmed the GitHub Pages source is correctly set to the gh-pages branch.


Despite these efforts, the app still shows the default page on GitHub Pages.

I have a few questions for you. You need to update your issue. If you share the content of the next.config.js file and the github workflow yaml file, I would like to give a clearer answer and help you. I also have an additional question. Have you made any changes to the default scripts in the package.json file or are you running your operations with the default scripts when publishing the project?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In the Options page of the repository, I had to select the gh-pages branch instead of the master branch. That's it.
